# Nginx proxy_pass "Cannot GET", while desired domain displays normally

Tags: nginx, node.js

Here's my issue: I'm trying to do a proxy_pass at "/" (located at test.co) to a separate domain - webflow.test.co - while all other requests "/(.+)" go to my nodejs server. Unfortunately, with my current setup, I get an error "Cannot GET /index.html". This is strange to me, especially because going to webflow.test.co directly works fine.

Here's my code - any help is greatly, greatly appreciated. Been stuck on this awhile, and I'm new to nginx:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

# Redirect all non-HTTPS to non-WWW HTTPS
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name "~^(?:www\.)?(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect WWW HTTP to non-WWW HTTP
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name webflow.test.co;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webflow.test.co;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

# Reverse-proxy to http://nodejs
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^(?!www\.).*$";

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location ~ /(.+) {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

EDIT requested by @Tero ilkanen: The two Redirect blocks at the top (non-HTTPS and non-WWW) are legacy, but I assume I want them to stay. What I'm adding is functionality for the following: I need to be able to go to the homepage (in this case, test.co) and have it proxy to webflow.test.co, keeping the host intact. All other requests need to be sent to the Nodejs server - namely, test.co/api, test.co/media, test.co/login, and a few others. This is just a test run - once I get this problem fixed, I'll add support for specific URLs. But for now, homepage > webflow.test.co, everything else to the nodejs server. I've since added the two location blocks back in to the single Nodejs server block, but I'm now getting an infinite redirect loop. I'll edit and put updated code below.

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

# Redirect all non-HTTPS to non-WWW HTTPS
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name "~^(?:www\.)?(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect WWW HTTP to non-WWW HTTP
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}

# Reverse-proxy to http://nodejs
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^(?!www\.).*$";

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webflow.test.co;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /(.+) {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does nginx `error.log` show? Why do you have the two virtual server blocks when your question implies you want a different behaviour in one virtual host depending on the path? Please add additional information into the question, and elaborate the use cases more clearly.

Comment: @Tero ilkanen The nginx error.log shows nothing. I have two virtual server blocks for a pretty complex reason - and that is, i have no idea what im doing :) I didn't have success with putting them in a single server block. Keeping the same location blocks, but putting them in the single server block, led to an infinite redirect loop that I had trouble solving. I changed it to this, and called it progress. You may be informing me that I'm wrong, and that I need to go back to debugging that problem - if so, I'll create a new thread, unless you have suggestions on why that might be happening.

Comment: It is just difficult to understand what your exact goals are. Please provide example URLs and descriptions what those example URLs should show, and include them in the question.

Comment: Editted accordingly.

Comment: One more thing to add: Removing the two redirect blocks at the top doesn't change anything.

Comment: Also: removing the Host header on the location / block fixes the problem... but, of course, leaves me with the webflow.test.co URL. Just extra information. I feel this is a separate question altogether (these new edits), so I'm going to open a new thread. Feel free to hop in: https://serverfault.com/questions/872141/nginx-redirect-loop-with-multiple-proxy-pass-and-host-header